# Number theory question from 2017 MO

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, contest-math, fractions, rational-numbers

> **(Asian-Pacific Olympiad $2017$).** Let $a, b, c$ be positive rational
> numbers with $abc = 1$. Suppose there exist positive integers $x, y, z$ for which
> $a^x +b^y +c^z$ is an integer. Prove that when $a, b, c$ are written as a fractions in
> lowest terms, the numerators are perfect powers.

Solution from book OTIS excerpts:

It is suffcient to prove the following claim.

**Claim:** Let $p$ be a prime. If $\nu_{p}(a) > 0$ then $\nu_{p}(a)$ is divisible by $\frac{y+z}{\gcd(y,z)}$ .

**Proof.**

Note $\nu_{p}(a) + \nu_{p}(b) + \nu_{p}(c) = 0$.

WLOG assume $\nu_{p}(c) < 0$
(hence $\nu_{p}(c^z) < 0)$.

Then since $\nu_{p}(a^x + b^y + c^z) \geq 0$
and $\nu_{p}(a^x) > 0$, we must have
$$\nu_{p}(b^y) = \nu_{p}(c^z) \Rightarrow y\nu_{p}(b) = z\nu_{p}p(c)\,.$$

Thus we may set $\nu_{p}(b) = -z'k$ and $\nu_{p}(c) = -y'k$ where $y' =\frac{y}{\gcd(y,z)}$ and
$z' =\frac{z}{\gcd(y,z)}$ . Then
$$\nu_{p}(a) =-\nu_{p}(b) -\nu_{p}(c) = k \cdot (y' + z')$$
as needed.

Therefore the numerator of a is a perfect $\frac{y+z}{\gcd(y,z)}$th power.

---

I understood the solution pretty much entirely except for one thing. Why must $\nu_{p}(b^y) = \nu_{p}(c^z)$ be true? Also because i guess that, because i am unable to understand this, i also don't understand the motivation for choosing such $y'$ and $z'$. Why not just just $x$ and $y$ instead? Could someone please provide a simple explanation? Also if you have your own solution i would be very much interested in seeing it and also getting to know the motivation behind your solutions. Thanks.

Comment: This is basically the ultrametric property: $v_p(A+B)\geq\min\{v_p(A),v_p(B)\}$ with equality when $v_p(A)\neq v_p(B)$.  Since we already know $v_p(a^x)>0$ and $v_p(a^x+b^y+c^z)\geq 0$, we must have $v_p(b^y+c^z)\geq 0$.  Since we also know $v_p(c^z)<0$ we are forced to have $v_p(b^y)=v_p(c^z)$.

Comment: @user10354138 wait but if $v_p(b^y)=v_p(c^z)$ then both of them are negative. But you said that we take the least power as our answer. But then the least power here $v_p(a^x+b^y+c^z)$ is negative then isn't it? then why does this inequality hold? M sorry if m acting really dumb m just a newbie.