# Proving that if $a^{x}+b^{y}+c^{z}\in \mathbb{Z}$, $a,b,c$ can be expressed as $\frac{m^{k}}{n}$, $k\gt 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q^{+}}$, $abc=1$. There are $x,y,z\in \mathbb{N}\smallsetminus \{0\}$, such that $a^{x}+b^{y}+c^{z}\in \mathbb{Z}$. The task is to prove that $a,b,c$ can be expressed as  $\frac{m^{k}}{n}$ for coprime $m,n$, while $k\gt 1$.

I expanded the equations and tried to deduce some useful relationships but without much success. The condition is obviously false for whole numbers which got me thinking about the properies of rationals expressable in such a manner. Do you know of any neat properties that might be relevant in this problem? Are they a well known mathematical structure in general?

Thanks for any help with the proof.

Comment: What's the soource of this question, please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the original source. It was supplied to me second-hand.

Comment: So, please ask the person who gave it to you.

Comment: Apparently it is from their personal collection of interesting problems they found all over the internet. I tried finding it myself, but tracking it down is rather difficult. Is there any specific reason why you ask? If the question is unclear I can clarify any confusion.

Comment: Knowing the source of a problem often gives a clue as to the techniques intended for its solution. It also insures against the possibility that a question is from an ongoing competition, or an entrance exam from some program.

Comment: Looks like it's this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754115/number-theory-question-from-2017-mo

Comment: Thank you! Could not find it before but that is indeed the question I asked.